# how to Avoid re computation of embeddings with Chroma

Tags: chromadb, vector-database

i have a chromadb which have over 50k documents.
1 - i did `vectordb.get(include=['embeddings', 'documents', 'metadatas'])` to get all the documents, ids, ... stored in the chroma
2 - i did some filtering and i end up with a portion of what .get() returns
3 - i want to create another chroma retreiver but only with the new records
the problem is that i can't find a way to not re calculate the embdedings

i tried srearching in the documentation but  the only function that creates vector db from lagchain documents is `from_documents` and the later excpects a embedin function , basicly it wil recalulate them , but i already have them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the "embeddings" keyword in your get:

```
 data = vectordb.get(include=['embeddings', 'documents', 'metadatas', 'embeddings'])
```

then you can use `data['embeddings']` to add those in your new collection:

```
collection.add(embeddings=data['embeddings'] ...
```

Comment: @dnontaner Chroma() has an attribute called _collection i combined with what you tell me and it works , thanks king